# how to replace the &quot; into " using php string function

Tags: php, email

This is a simple issue but I have been unable to solve this. My problem is that I am sending email using the libmail class.

```
$message = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(strip_tags($message)));
```

Everything is working fine but if I use the " in the text, it will be diaslayed in the mail  as `&quot;`. I have already tried:

```
mail ($strTo, $this->xheaders['Subject'], htmlentities($this->fullBody), $this->headers,"-f $rtpth");
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Leave out the htmlspecialchars and htmlentites calls, they are converting your quotes to html entites, which means that your " character is converted to & quot;

Comment: +1 Good advice. You should only need to call htmlspecialchars for data that will be printed as HTML.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a recent version of PHP (v5.1 or better), you can use `htmlspecialchars_decode` to .. uh... decode htmlspecialchars.

See here for the manual page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use htmlspecialchars when defining $message

By the way, for decoding html entities - http://lv.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Answer (score -1):

set ENT_NOQUOTES, " should then not be replaced `htmlspecialchars($string,ENT_NOQUOTES)`http://php.net/manual/de/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: he is probably just misusing htmlentities and htmlspecialchars. This will render those functions useless in other context and may weaken security.

Comment: well, if you have a Problem with his code vote his question down, not a legit Answer how to prevent htmlspecialchars from converting quotes... jezz ...